# Trying to call parse.com cloud function using maigun route action

Tags: parse-platform, mailgun

I'm trying to use a parse.com cloud function in a mailgun route action (forward).

My action is like this (with my app id and JS key included of course):

forward("https://myAppId:javascript-key:myJSkey@api.parse.com/1/functions/hello")

In the mailgun logs, I see it call, but I get the following error:

HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Server response: 401 HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

My function is just a simple response.send("OK");

Obviously I'm missing something.

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is that the [Cloud Code calling convention](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-calling) requires you use special Parse headers, not just keys: it may be different if its being called from a browser with sets the referer headers. I'm not sure you'll be able to call it this way directly from Mailgun: you may need a proxy of some sort.

EDIT: I think you'll need to use the [Express Webhook implementation](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks) instead, and then you can use standard basic authentication. Cloud Code is really for cases where you have control over the HTTP client you're using.

Comment: Try using javascript-key= as a prefix to your JavaScript key (note that I'm using a = sign and not a colon).